# Null hypothesis for overidentifying restrictions tests in statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running some overidentification tests for IV regression using `statsmodels`.
I have 2 endogenous variables and 3 instruments, which I suspect are all good: first stage F-stats is well over 10, so they are relevant, also plausibly exogenous. H0 in the `statsmodels` Sargan's (also Wooldridge) overidentification test is: "`The model is not overidentified`". And according to the results below I cannot reject this null. The result implies my model is not overidentified and some of the instruments are NOT valid, so I better NOT use them. However, I suspect that H0 is simply misstated and should be "`The model is overidentified`". Overidentification means that there are more instruments than endogenous variables and the instruments are relevant, so I don't want to reject it.

Can I be sure that null hypotheses for `result.sargan` and `result.wooldridge_overid` in `statsmodels` are formulated correctly?

[image]

Comment: Use `linearmodels`.  It has much more thorough testing that the IV in statsmodels. It also supports additional estimators.

Comment: thank you, will try that. I have only used `linearmodels` for some FE regression and 3SLS model so far, used `statsmodels` for all else. Offtopic, but pity also that regularized output tables are not working in `statsmodels` too

Comment: Can you report the issue on GitHub for statsmodels?